# How do I change the width of the table to the text width in Latex?

Tags: tables, width

I made a table, but the table does not fit on the page. The code for the table is:

```
\begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \label{my-label}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
                         & x                                             & 0                                                & 0                                                         & 0                                              & 1                                               \\ \hline
                      & 1                                             & x                                                & 0                                                         & 0                                              & 1                                               \\ \hline
             & 1                                             & 1                                                & x                                                         & 1                                              & 1                                               \\ \hline
                       & 1                                             & 1                                                & 0                                                         & x                                              & 1                                               \\ \hline
                      & 0                                             & 0                                                & 0                                                         & 0                                              & x                                               \\ \hline
            & 3                                             & 2                                                & 0                                                         & 1                                              & 4                                               \\ \hline
                                    & 4                                             & 3                                                & 1                                                         & 2                                              & 5                                               \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

How do I change the width of the table so that it fits on the page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. You can  code-blocks either by indenting them by four spaces or using the `{}` on the gui - for in-line code use back-ticks.

Comment: You need narrower column headers. If this is not possible then use the [multirow](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package to have the column labels span more than one row. I'd also drop the `\hlines` as this will look much better -- see the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual for a discussion on best practice in writing tables.

Answer (score 2):

Your `tabular` environment is currently not allowing line breaks in the header cells, for two reasons. First, the five data columns are of type `c`, which doesn't allow line breaks. Second, the header cells are actually typeset using the `l` column type, which doesn't allow line breaks either.

I suggest you (a) get rid of the `\multicolumn{1}{l}` "wrappers", (b) use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, and (c) use a centered version of the `X` column type for the five data columns.

I would also get rid of all vertical rules. That'll immediately give the table a more "open" and inviting look.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page size parameters suitable
\usepackage{float,tabularx} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % create a more open look
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}      % default value: 6pt
\caption{Being cool} \label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{5}{C} @{}}
\hline
& Cool as much as possible 
& The COP as high as possible 
& Have as much input power as possible 
& Cool as quick as possible 
& System as safe as possible 
\\ \hline
Cool as much as possible             & x & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
The COP as high as possible          & 1 & x & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
Have as much input power as possible & 1 & 1 & x & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
Cool as quick as possible            & 1 & 1 & 0 & x & 1 \\ \hline
System as safe as possible           & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x \\ \hline
                                     & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ \hline
Weight factor                        & 4 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```